# Add edges between 2 components of graph with Euler Cycle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, graph-theory

Each of 2 components of graph $G$ has Euler Cycle. At least, how many edges should be added to the graph $G$ to make it a new graph $G$ have Euler Cycle?

**My ideas:**

If we have Euler cycle, so every vertex should have even degree.
So, if we add an edge between components, 2 vertexes will not have even degree.
So, we can add another edge and 2 more vertexes will not have even degree.

I finished at 4 edges $\implies$ all vertexes of new graph have even degree; but I think it's not eulerian.

So, any algorithms, theorems etc. for this case?

Comment: The theorem is that if a connected graph has all vertices of even degree, then it's Eulerian. But you can do better than your 4-edge solution - this is not based on hard theorems, just based on thinking of the right thing to do.